# How to pass jsf commandLink action property value in javascript

Tags: jsf

I need to pass the string value of action attribute of jsf commandLink tag.

Here's my code:

```
<h:commandLink id='link' action="#{Bean.selectLink}" 
 onclick="myFunction(document.getElementById('link'))">
</h:commandLink> 
//value is coming as null
```

I also tried `onclick="myFunction(this)"` but its value is coming as the url of the page before navigation due to commandLink action. I want to pass the value of action attribute i.e. "#{Bean.selectLink}".

I tried passing it as `onclick="myFunction(#{Bean.selectLink})"` but it showed error PropertyNotFoundException: selectLink property not found in Bean.

I have tried `oncomplete` attribute in place of onclick but nothing happened then.

Please help me figure out this. Thanks

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Comment: Could you provide any sample code?

Comment: Hi Biker, I edited my question. Can you please check once.